# best way of importing data into mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, ms-access

i have a table with 500,000 rows and about 10 columns that is in access

how do i import it into mysql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dump to csv and import csv using mysqlimport is another option.

Comment: To add to @jishi - the MySQL front-end tool HeidiSQL has a built-in CSV import option that works quite well.

Comment: Iam using MySqlWorkBench. How can i import data that already exists?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a writeup on the subject.

http://www.kitebird.com/articles/access-migrate.html

This outlines 3 strategies to accomplish your task of migrating to MySQL

- Telling Microsoft Access to Export Its Own Tables
- Converters That Generate Intermediate Files (i.e. CSV)
- Converters That Perform Direct Data Transfer

Also, some [Forum Discussion](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?65,296287,296287) on the issue.

And finally, software exists ([Access MySQL Import, Export & Convert](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/access-mysql-import-export-convert.htm)) that might do the trick also.  Note: I've never used this so I really don't know how good it works, I just added it for completeness.

As you can see, there are several ways to accomplish this, I recommend checking out each one and choosing the one that **works best for you**.

Answer (score 1):

See:

**[Access2MySQL](http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Programming/Databases_and_Networks/Access2MySQL_Pro.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Try **[SQL Data Examiner](http://www.sqlaccessories.com/SQL_Data_Examiner/)**

Answer (score 1):

Bullzip has a free Access to MySQL tool. Really useful and quick.

p.s. Relations are not included

http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php

Answer (score 0):

[Access to MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php) is a small program that will convert Microsoft Access Databases to MySQL

[image]

**@Wizard interface.**

**@Transfer data directly from one server to another.**

@Create a dump file.

**@Select tables to transfer.**

**@Select fields to transfer.**

@Transfer password protected databases.

@Supports both shared security and user-level security.

@Optional transfer of indexes.

**@Optional transfer of records.**

@Optional transfer of default values in field definitions.

@Identifies and transfers auto number field types.

@Command line interface.

**@Easy install, uninstall and upgrade.**