# MDB file to Mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, ms-access

I have MDB file with data and Mysql database also, I want to insert some specific fields of MDB file to My mysql database, Is there any mechanism to covert it and mention some specific fileds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2821283/1256403 @harihara

Answer (score 1):

If you have Microsoft Access, you can create a link to the MySQL database using the appropriate ODBC driver for MySQL. But it's probably easier to install MySQL Workbench and use the migration assistant (in this case, you'll have to use the ODBC driver for Access).